How do I know which chip antenna to use for esp32-c3?
https://www.sudo.is/docs/esphome/boards/esp32c3supermini/
I am trying to make a board using esp32-c3 as above.
I am going to use a chip antenna for the antenna.
The above site provides a schematic, but I can't find any information about the antenna chip.
Can you tell me the model name of the chip antenna used on the above site?
Or can you recommend a chip antenna that can be used for esp32-c3?
Thank you.

This will probably be closed as a request for specific product recommendation. Instead, just choose a popular (i.e. well-stocked) 2.4 GHz WiFi/Bluetooth chip antenna from a distributor, then carefully follow the datasheet for layout. You'll still probably need to adjust the matching components which requires test equipment.

If you are a hobbyist that produce one or a few boards, you are better to buy the existing board or ESP32 WiFi modules (that includes the antenna) from Espressif. There are many vendors provides chip antenna for 2.4GHz but chip antenna is difficult to optimised even you done your part of impedance matching during PCB design. If you are buying a million, the vendor will provide antenna tuning service for you to determine the value of UC8, UC9 and UR9 matching circuitry after you produce your PCB.
